# Taking ROI of a MR image and get the mean intensity of that ROI

Tags: image, matlab, roi

We are doing a laboration study and we want to take a ROI (decide an area in the image) of the bottles in the MR image using MATLAB to get a mean intensity value. We have tried roipoly, a function in MATLAB, but the thing is that the output will create a binary mask image, and that is not what we want.[The phantom which illustrates five bottles (Click to see the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdvUc.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After you get the mask using `roipoly`, you can get the ROI (as a linear array) by doing `roi_data = image(mask)`